# SO jobs message sidebar styling bug

Tags: bug, design, jobs-messages

Just noticed a styling bug on SO job messages inbox app. It appears that the 'Messages' sidebar container is missing a left margin and/or padding. This is only happening with window width of 980px and greater.

Here's a screenshot of the sidebar on a > 980px window width:

[image: sidebar on a > 980px window width]

and here's the same sidebar looking all fancy on a < 980px window width:

[image: sidebar on a < 980px window width]

Comment: But but but...its responsive I tell ya!