# Jobs Messages section design is weird

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

Can the messages section be moved to the left navigation section? It's confusing how it's like a nested frame.

Current design:

[image]

Proposed:

[image]

I noticed other people had some similar issues/suggestions w.r.t. [getting to your messages section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358339/get-to-jobs-messages-from-developer-story) and [the styling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373457/so-jobs-message-sidebar-styling-bug).

Comment: And for those of us who turn off the sidebar? A fallback to the current design, perhaps?

Comment: I hope you rejected Bill Gates' offer. Sending a cat photo is unprofessional. They should send dog photos instead.

Comment: Those messages made me laugh so hard, I hope they are real.

Comment: Oh and can someone give that poor question mark icon some padding on the left?

Answer (score 4):

Great suggestion. I'm setting this as status-review because we are thinking about how to improve discoverability of the Messages inbox but we don't have a set solution or schedule for it yet. Thanks for the feedback!